# Rails 4 strong parameters without required parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

I'm using Rails 4 and I don't know what is the best way to use strong parameters without required parameters. So, that's what I did:

```
def create
device = Device.new(device_params)
.................
end

private

def device_params
  if params[:device]
    params.require(:device).permit(:notification_token)
  else
    {}
  end
end
```

My device model does not validate presence of anything.
I know I could do something like that too:

```
device = Device.new
device.notification_token = params[:device][:notification_token] if params[:device] && params[:device][:notification_token]
```

Is there any conventions or the right way to do that?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can use `fetch` instead of `require`.

```
def device_params
   params.fetch(:device, {}).permit(:notification_token)
end
```

Above will return empty hash when device is not present in params

Documentation [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#more-examples).

Comment: @usha is there any problem or security issue leaving it as `params.permit(:name, :last_name, :age)` ?