# Failure/Error: click_button "Add Movie" ActionController::ParameterMissing: param is missing or the value is empty: movie

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I've been looking at other answers and I'm still getting this error with params missing. I'm guessing it's a paperclip issue, but after searching through the docs, I can't find anything resolving this issue.

My Feature Spec

````
scenario "An Admin creates a new movie" do 
      visit "/"
    click_link "Add New Movie"```

    fill_in "Title", with: "Creating first movie"
    fill_in "Synopsis", with: "Lorem Ipsum"
    fill_in "Year Released", with: "Date"
    click_button "Add Movie"

    expect(page).to have_content("Movie has been created")
    expect(page.current_path).to eq(root_path)
    expect(page).to have_content("Created by: #{@kyle.email}")```

end
````

My movie model

```
class Movie < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :comments
  belongs_to :admin

  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :synopsis, presence: true
  validates :year_released, presence: true

  has_attached_file :photo, styles: { medium: "300x200>", thumb: "100x100>" },         default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
```

validates_attachment_file_name :photo, matches: [/png\Z/, /jpe?g\Z/]```

My Controller

```
def update
  if @movie.update(movie_params)
    flash[:success] = "Movie has been updated"
    redirect_to @movie
  else
    flash.now[:danger] = "Movie has not been updated"
    render :edit
  end
end

private

def movie_params
  params.require(:movie).permit(:title, :synopsis, :year_released, :photo)
end
```

My _form.html.erb

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class='control-label col-md-3'>
    <%= f.label :photo %>
  </div> 
  <div class='col-md-10'>
    <%= f.file_field :photo, class: "btn btn-primary btn-sl pull-left" %>
  </div>

<div class='form-group'>
<div class='col-md-offset-1 col-md-11'>
  <%= f.submit "Add Movie", class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg pull-right" %>
</div>
```

The error

````
 Failure/Error: click_button "Add Movie"
 ActionController::ParameterMissing:
 param is missing or the value is empty: movie```
````

My [Github](https://github.com/kylestengline/moviesmoviesmovies/tree/development) if neccessary.

Comment: how is your form_for look like

Comment: ```<%= form_for(@movie) %> 
 <%= f.label :title %> 
<%= f.text_field :title, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Title of movie', autofocus: true %> 
<%= f.label :synopsis %>
 <%= f.text_area :synopsis, rows: 10, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Synopsis' %>
<%= f.label :photo %>
<%= f.file_field :photo, class: "btn btn-primary btn-sl pull-left" %>```

Comment: error occurred while updating movie?

Comment: Well, it's a test that I'm writing and the test fails for the "Add Movie" button saying ```Failure/Error: click_button "Add Movie"
       ActionController::ParameterMissing:
       param is missing or the value is empty: movie``` But no, during the create movie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that's because you're using `require` in strong_params.

I changed your code to

```
def movie_params
  params.fetch(:movie, {}).permit(:title, :synopsis, :year_released, :photo)
end
```

and tests passed.

```
[retgoat@iMac-Roman ~/temp/moviesmoviesmovies]$ git:(development) rspec spec/features/creating_movies_spec.rb
DEPRECATION WARNING: use_transactional_fixtures= is deprecated and will  be removed from Rails 5.1 (use use_transactional_tests= instead). (called  from <top (required)> at   /Users/retgoat/temp/moviesmoviesmovies/spec/features/creating_movies_spec.rb:3)
..

Finished in 0.73751 seconds (files took 1.91 seconds to load)
2 examples, 0 failures
```

Also I tried it in browser all went as expected — I saw validation errors.

Documentation is [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#more-examples)

Also [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25914514/rails-4-strong-parameters-without-required-parameters) post was useful.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much! retgoat